# Delete a set of elements based on their id pattern using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, jqgrid

How to delete a set of rows from a table which have different row id patterns
 using javascript eg: we have three set of rowids.(rowid:HS_AFI_H_2000012",rowid="HS_AFI_H_2000012_HV_498661_HVK_1",rowid : H_113_A_444_B_2). We need to delete third pattern.

Code Sample:

```
<tr role="row" id="H_113_A_444_B_10" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" aria-describedby="result-table_id">undefined</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Run of House - Double" aria-describedby="result-table_name"></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="NA" aria-describedby="result-table_count"><span class="count">NA</span></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="2013-08-23" aria-describedby="result-table_seta_begin_min">2013-08-23</td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" id="HS_AFI_H_2000012_HV_498661_HVK_1" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" aria-describedby="result-table_id">undefined</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Run of House - Double" aria-describedby="result-table_name"></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="NA" aria-describedby="result-table_count"><span class="count">NA</span></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="2013-08-23" aria-describedby="result-table_seta_begin_min">2013-08-23</td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" id="H_113_A_444_B_10" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" aria-describedby="result-table_id">undefined</td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="Run of House - Double" aria-describedby="result-table_name"></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="NA" aria-describedby="result-table_count"><span class="count">NA</span></td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" title="2013-08-23" aria-describedby="result-table_seta_begin_min">2013-08-23</td>
</tr>
```

We Need to delete the third row id pattern.

Comment: `H_113_A_444_B_2` delete id of this pattern

Comment: Does this mean elements with ID of `H_nnn_A_nnn_B_n` should be removed? Your question (_if any_) is not clear, at least for me.

Comment: The fact that those elements are in a table is not very relevant here. (It could be a list or divs...). I renamed the question accordingly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/d2h7k/